# Streamlit: plot mathematical function dynamically with parameters

Tags: javascript, plot, frontend, plotly, streamlit

I am looking for a solution to plot dynamically mathematical function in 2D on a web page made with Streamlit.
For example I would like to plot a normal distribution and have two sliders to set the mean and st dev of the distribution. I am looking for something that would continuously update.
There are plenty of solution to plot static graphic function. Do you have any clue of which lib I should use ?
I did not found example for this topic on internet. Nor specific solution. Would it be possible with plotta.js ? But I am sure some did have the same need as me.
Would plottly.js work for this ? (I do not want the backend to compute the functions).
If anyone as a code pen, that would be perfect.

Cheers

Comment: If you are talking about using Streamlit, then use a Python plotting library like altair or plotly. Using Streamlit and then writing JavaScript defeats the point.

Answer (score 2):

Sample code using matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import streamlit as st
 
x = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
 
def normal_dist(x , mean , sd):
    prob_density = np.exp(-0.5*((x-mean)/sd)**2) / np.sqrt(np.pi * sd**2)
    return prob_density
 
mean = st.slider(label='input mean', min_value=0., max_value=100., value=4.)
sd = st.slider(label='input std dev', min_value=0.1, max_value=100., value=4.)
 
pdf = normal_dist(x,mean,sd)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x, pdf , color = 'blue')
plt.xlabel('Data points')
plt.ylabel('Probability Density')
st.pyplot(fig)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for you answer,
But this will actually generate a png from the backend and send it to the front end.
The solution is working but it won't be as smooth as if the curve was computed in js by the frontend.

Comment: Have a look on [components api](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/components/components-api)